# NodeJS mongoose bug in if statement

Tags: node.js, mongoose

The code should work like that: If target username and logged in user username is in the same fight then the fight should not be created and user should be redirected to `/arena`. But the problem is that even though when I finish the fight then fast hit F5 the new fight with the same user and same target creates again. What could cause this problem ?

```
app.get('/arena/fight/user/:username', async (req, res) => {

    User.findById(req.session.userId).then((user) => {
        if(req.params.username === user.username) {
            return res.redirect('/arena');
        }
    });

    const target = await User.findOne({username: req.params.username});
    const user = await User.findById(req.session.userId);
    const fight = await TempFight.findOne({user: user.username});
    if(fight && target.username === fight.target) {
       return res.redirect('/arena');
    } else {
       const battleId = uuid4();
       const newtempFight = TempFight({
          target: target.username,
          user: user.username,
          code: battleId
       });
       await newtempFight.save();
    }


    if(req.session.userId) {        

     res.render(__dirname + '/views/arena/battle', {messages, user, enemy, userItems, enemyItems, liveitems, fights, lostFights});
    } else {
        return res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what happens when a fight is finished, is it deleted from the database?

Comment: @Christian no. When fight is started it expires after one minute only. You finish the fight in less than minute. Like in 10 sec max

Comment: If I finish battle not so fast this seems to do not work, but if I hit enemy in one hit and do fast refresh it creates the same record in DB but `if` statement should not let that happen

Comment: Note that `save` is an asynchronous operation so you should `await` it in your code. Else it could be saved after the fight is finished.

Comment: @Christian Could you implement `await` for me in my example please ?

Comment: You don't need to use `async/await` but the code gets cleaner imo.
In your code above, you could try just add `return` before the call to `newtempFight.save();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182651/discussion-between-abraom-185-and-christian).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
app.get('/arena/fight/user/:username', async (req, res) => {
   const user = await User.findById(req.session.userId);
   if(req.params.username === user.username) {
      return res.redirect('/arena');
   }
   const target = await User.findOne({username: req.params.username});
   const fight = await TempFight.findOne({user: user.username});
   if(fight && target.username === fight.target) {
      return res.redirect('/arena');
   } else {
      const battleId = uuid4();
      const newtempFight = TempFight({
         target: target.username,
         user: user.username,
         code: battleId
      });
      await newtempFight.save();
   }
   if(req.session.userId) {        
      res.render(__dirname + '/views/arena/battle', {messages, user, 
         enemy, userItems, enemyItems, liveitems, fights, lostFights});
   } else {
      return res.redirect('/');
   }
});
```

Comment: When I use this in my route I get `await is only valid in async function`

Comment: You need to use the `async` keyword before the function signature. See example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: Okay I added this to my code. Still didn't fixed the bug. I'm loosing my mind lol

Comment: What does the calling code look like? Might be that some `Promise` isn't resolved higher up in the call chain?

Comment: The code needs to be called from somewhere else. Or is this your route handling code? In that case, please post the whole function.

Comment: I've edited the code in my response so that also the first call to `User.findById` is `await`:ed

Comment: I probably need to rewrite everything... This works on the first fight. Then when I pick another user I can spam the fights. Something is just wrong here...

Comment: OH MY GOD. `TempFight.findOne` THIS MIGHT BE ISSUE. WE NEED TO USE `find()` because there are more fights than one versus another users! This is why probably this works when there is one fight. But I can start spamming from second fight